# How would I do this in WiX?

Tags: wix

I need to install a program that consists of several files, like most Windows programs do.  But:

1. It needs to work without Admin.  The app is normally put in an Application-Local folder (something under %APPDATA%).
2. Must not show any UI or prompts (if no error).  The existing code just extracts everything to the app-local directory and then runs it.  (It's smarter than that, but it shows how simple it is to use ad-hoc code in this case)
3. Download some files.  Files that may not be needed, or are not changed in an update, won't be in the self-extracting EXE, but should be downloaded from a URL.
4. The C++ runtime DLLs are usually present in System32, from previous apps that used the official redistributable MM.  But if not, download the files to the app-local directory.  That is different from (3) in that rather than seeing if an identical file is already present in the target location, it looks to see if LoadLibrary works.  (Likewise for installed TTF fonts)

I'm overwhelmed by just looking at the WiX docs page, and wonder if this is to ill-fitted to use WiX.  So, could you point to specific instructions on how to do each of these?

Thanks.

Comment: May I get this taken off hold now?  I really do want an answer so I hope it gets seen again, soon.

Answer (score 2):

With just Windows Installer, no. Windows Installer either always shows at least a very minimal startup UI or, if invoked with appropriate command-line arguments, none at all, even if there is an error.

You could use the Windows Installer API to install an MSI to control how much UI is shown and to show your own, including on error. But, WiX gives you a platform for that.

The WiX Toolset has a bootstrapper/bundler/chainer/downloader/reboot handler/package manager for MSIs and EXEs. Since it's engine is called "burn", bootstrappers created with it are sometimes called "burn bundles." Burn has an extension point for application concerns such as a UI, called a bootstrapper application. The standard bootstrapper application always shows a UI. You can write your own in C++ or .NET.

That said, you should realize two things. Windows Installer is a component manager. It has a database of installed components (such as files) that can be shared across products. It is not suited as a self-extracting archive. The WiX bootstrapper is somewhat similar, being a package manager. It has a database of installed packages that can be shared across products. It is not simply a bootstrapper.

I'm not so sure about your point 4. It is cleaner to properly install redistributables using their vendors' installers, which ideally can be run silently and can do their own checking for previous installation and make a quick exit to success. But, if you find documentation on how to check for previous installation by file or registry searching, you can declare those in your WiX bootstrapper to bypass downloading and installing those packages.

In the WiX bootstrapper, packages can be marked a permanent so they aren't uninstalled with the product is uninstalled. That could apply to C++ runtimes. That way, products that don't using the WiX bootstrapper won't be broken by your uninstall.

BTW—WiX itself and Visual Studio use the WiX bootstrapper.

Comment: I can't use the VS10 RTL Redistributable installer because it's not invisible and it requires admin.
Good food for thought of how a component manager isn't a good fit for a self-extracting archive.  I'm just hoping to avoid a large static linked exe to be just installer, and handling downloads.